# Unity program stopped responding because of a infinite while loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop

Hello stack overflow users! I was creating a game in unity 2018.2.2f1. All went great, but i missplaced the order of code lines in the program --> which caused a infite while loop appearing. I didn't know it would be infinite so I runned the program. Now my unity window is unselectable when i click on the icon, and when i enter the window, everything is frozen. I would close the program trough task manager, but i didnt save my files and i can't even save the project. Is there any way for me to save the project when it is in this state? My unity didn't crash, it just froze.
Here is my FIXED c# code if that somehow helps (and i am in visual studio):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10f;
    private Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
    private string direction = "none";
    private bool canMoveAgain = true;
    private bool go = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "wall (3)" && direction == "down")
        {
            go = false;
        }
        if (collision.collider.name == "wall (2)" && direction == "up")
        {
            go = false;
        }
        if (collision.collider.name == "wall" && direction == "left")
        {
            go = false;
        }
        if (collision.collider.name == "wall (1)" && direction == "right")
        {
            go = false;
        }
    }
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && canMoveAgain)
        {
            direction = "down";
            go = true;
            canMoveAgain = false;
            while (go)
            {
                velocity = new Vector3(0,-1,0);
                transform.position += velocity;
            }
            velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            direction = "none";
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && canMoveAgain)
        {
            direction = "up";
            go = true;
            canMoveAgain = false;
            while (go)
            {
                velocity = new Vector3(0, +1, 0);
                transform.position += velocity;
            }
            velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            direction = "none";
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && canMoveAgain)
        {
            direction = "left";
            go = true;
            canMoveAgain = false;
            while (go)
            {
                velocity = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
                transform.position += velocity;
            }
            velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            direction = "none";
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && canMoveAgain)
        {
            direction = "right";
            go = true;
            canMoveAgain = false;
            while (go)
            {
                velocity = new Vector3(+1, 0, 0);
                transform.position += velocity;
            }
            velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            direction = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @derHugo thank you for the code recomendation, can you fix me whit the unity freezing tho?

Comment: Related, https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/panic-button-40167

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Do not close Unity.
You got two things you can try to do.

- Luckily your code has a backup when you press run. 
  It is inside the Temp folder. The Temp folder will be replaced if you press run again. Copy the project to somewhere safe.
- Attach a Debugger, this can be either Visual Studio or MonoDevelop. Once they are attached to Unity just click pause. And you're free to save your project.

I hope you find this answer before it's too late.

Answer (score 2):

You do

```
while (go)
{
    velocity = new Vector3(+1, 0, 0);
    transform.position += velocity;
}
```

but `go` is never set to false **inside the loop**.

`OnCollisionEnter` is never executed since the `while` is still being executed => freeze.

since `Update` is called each frame anyway you should rather move that part to a separate `if(go)` block after checking the Inputs ..

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.name == "wall (3)" && direction == "down"
        || collision.collider.name == "wall (2)" && direction == "up"
        || collision.collider.name == "wall" && direction == "left"
        || collision.collider.name == "wall (1)" && direction == "right")
    {
        go = false;
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        direction = "none"
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && canMoveAgain)
    {
        direction = "down";
        go = true;
        canMoveAgain = false;
        velocity = -Vector3.up;
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && canMoveAgain)
    {
        direction = "up";
        go = true;
        canMoveAgain = false;
        velocity = Vector3.up;
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && canMoveAgain)
    {
        direction = "left";
        go = true;
        canMoveAgain = false;

        velocity = -Vector3.right;
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && canMoveAgain)
    {
        direction = "right";
        go = true;
        canMoveAgain = false;
        velocity = Vector3.right;
    }

    if(go)
    {
        transform.position += velocity;
    }    
}
```

---

Note that currently your code is also frame rate dependent. You might want to rather use something like

```
public float moveSpeed;

...

transform.position += velocity * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

---

For the `direction` I would rather recommend an `enum` like

```
private enum MoveDirection
{
    None,
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

and use it e.g. like

```
direction = MoveDirection.Up;
```

and

```
if(direction == MoveDirection.Up)
```

which is more efficient than comparing strings.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: hey, thanks for clearing that out the way, but is there any way i can restore my files because i didnt save my unity project and it froze (but didnt go to the "not responding" state, the unity window just stopped responding to the player input(like ctr+s) but it is tehnically still running))

Comment: No there is no way unfortunately to get Unity out of there anymore. However the only thingaybe not saved would be the Scene afaik. Anything else should be there. Scripts are already saved anyway.

Comment: damn, i need to rebuild the game again, RIP

Comment: When was the last time you saved the scene? You'll only have to rebuild that one. I recommend to always create Prefabs of important stuff .. those are saved separately.

Comment: It may be possible to rescue the project by connecting a debugger (VisualStudio for example) and then dragging the instruction pointer out of the loop.

Comment: @eAi how do you mean? I never managed to get Unity interactive again since while debugging in e.g. VS Unity remains non-interacting until the debugging ends -> again it is stuck in the while loop